# How to convert this system of non-linear diff equations into vector form

Tags: functions, differential

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} = 0.25 x_1 - 0.001  x_1  x_2 - 2.5 \cdot (10^{-5})  x_1^2 \\
\frac{dx_2}{dt} = -0.5x_2 + 0.001  x_1 x_2 - 5 \cdot 10^{-4}  x_2^2
\end{cases}
$$
Initial conditions are $x_1(0) = 500$; $  x_2(0)=50$, if that's any help.

I need to transform this system into the form: dx/dt = f(x), where dx and f(x) are vectors.

I've read that I need to do Jacobian matrix, but I don't know what to do with it after I compute it.

Any help and ideas will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "x" you mean the vector $\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix}$ then your vector form is simply
$\frac{dx}{dt}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{dx_1}{dt} \\ \frac{dx_2}{dt} \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0.25x_1- 0.001x_1x_2- 2.5(10^{-5})x_1^2 \\ -0.5x_1+ 0.001x_1x_2- 5(10^{-4})x_2^2 \end{pmatrix}$